# How to encode plaintext ASCII or hex?

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc-mode

If I have a given ciphertext (from CBC mode with random IV with AES) that is in hexadecimal and its plaintext that is ASCII encoded, do I need to encode that ASCII plaintext into hex before encryption?

Plaintext is `"Pay Bob $100"`
ASCII `080 097 121 032 066 111 098 032 036 049 048 048`

and I am given cipher text `20814804c1767293b99f1d9cab3bc3e7 ac1e37bfb15599e5f40eef805488281d`.

Comment: For most (maybe even all) implementations the answer is `Yes`. You actually dont convert to `hex`but each character in the string should be converted to `bytes`. That is a plaintext `string` is converted to a `byte array` But my question to you is: What is the purpose? Encrypt the plaintext to get the exact ciphertext? You need to know the IV to accomplish this. Is there some other purpose to why you have both the ciphertext and plaintext?

Comment: Not clear what you asking. AES CBC works on block of bytes. It doesn't care what those bytes represent: hexadecimal numbers or ASCII encoding. So if you are talking about the input to the encryption routine then you don't have to encode anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a CT for the plaintext which is an ASCII encoding of the message "Pay Bob $100". I need to calculate the cipher text for the message "Pay Bob $500". I thought the IV would have been the first 16 bytes (as AES is used) of the cipher text? Im just getting confused as to whether i encode "Pay Bob $100" directly into hex first or whether i encode the ASCII version of the plaintext into hex. So do i put "Pay Bob $100" in to a hex converter or "080 097 121 032 066 111 098 032 036 049 048 048" into a hex converter.

Comment: (string) -> char encode -> (bytes) -> encrypt -> (bytes) -> hex encode -> (string) ->"send" -> "receive" -> (string) -> hex decode -> (bytes) -> decrypt -> (bytes) -> char decode -> (string).

Comment: Coursera homework :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to create a hexadecimal representation of the plaintext.

You are starting off with a text, which is likely a string within your application. This string may not yet have a default character-encoding such as ASCII or UTF-16LE. If there is no default encoding then you need to encode your plaintext into bytes (also known as a byte array or octet string). UTF-8 is the most widely used character encoding nowadays.

To make this a little more interesting, most IDE's and debuggers show bytes as hexadecimals when you view them. This is just a *representation* of the byte values in memory - the bytes are not encoded as hexadecimals in memory, you just view them as if they were.

Modern ciphers take plaintext bytes and convert them to ciphertext bytes. If you get back a string then the API has a default encoding method included with the algorithm (e.g. PHP is known to automatically encode). This is part of that API, not of the cipher itself.

Again, if the ciphertext is not automatically encoded, then you *may* have to encode the bytes yourself. You can use hexadecimals - easier for debugging as you can easily see the size of the ciphertext - or the more efficient Base64 encoding. But you only have to encode *if you need the ciphertext in a string instead of bytes*. One example where you do need a string is XML, as that is a text format (where the ciphertext is normally within a `CDATA` section).